# PHP Equivalent of CURL command

Tags: php, http, curl

What's the PHP equivalent of the following CURL command?

`curl -X POST -d "html=<html><body><h1 style="color: red;">Hello World!</h1>" http://example.com/post"`

Comment: We are really not `adapters`. Learn the curl functions.

Comment: Refer to the [cURL documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: Bro, do you even google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/post');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$data = array('html' => '<html><body><h1 style="color: red;">Hello World!</h1>'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

For future reference, it'd be useful to read [PHP's documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and scout out [other examples](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/curl-example.htm) before asking this type of question.